# How to find correct values for HWND window handles?

Tags: winapi, vb6, handle

```
WinRestore,% hwnd([1])
```

i have found in many programming language the use of hwnd. after searching on google it comes out to be handle. I didnt got more information on this. how programmer knows the value to put in, eg.

```
Const LB_GETTEXTLEN = &H18A
Const LB_GETTEXT = &H189
Const LB_GETCOUNT = &H18B
```

&h18a how he known, how will he use this?

this is the example program

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA"         (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As   Long
Const LB_GETTEXTLEN = &H18A
Const LB_GETTEXT = &H189
Const LB_GETCOUNT = &H18B

Private Function GetListItems(ByVal hList As Long) As Variant
Dim i As Long, nCount As Long, lItemLength As Long
Dim sItem() As String
nCount = SendMessage(hList, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, ByVal 0&)
For i = 0 To nCount - 1
   lItemLength = SendMessage(hList, LB_GETTEXTLEN, i, ByVal 0&)
   ReDim Preserve sItem(i)
   sItem(i) = String(lItemLength, 0)
   Call SendMessage(hList, LB_GETTEXT, i, ByVal sItem(i))
Next i
GetListItems = sItem
End Function
```

there are many such examples in all different languages but concept will be the same. so i want to learn it. what does it mean and how to use it.

another example from ahk 
    Gui,2:+hwndhwnd
    hwnd(2,hwnd)

Comment: There are constants (simply put,numerical values)  that are passed to various APIs (functions built into the operating system).  To know which ones to use, you read the DOCUMENTATION for the API you are using.  The docs will refer to the use of these constants.  The values can be found in other parts of the documentation, or you simply do a web search to find the values.

Answer (score 1):

Those are all window messages that you can find information about on the MSDN Documentation by googling them. See below links:

- [**`LB_GETTEXTLEN`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761315(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [**`LB_GETTEXT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761313(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [**`LB_GETCOUNT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775195(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can find them and other related messages by checking the documentation for the [**native List Box control**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775146(v=vs.85).aspx#messages).

As for the numbers they're hexadecimal numbers which are (usually) mentioned in the documentation. But since these aren't you'll have to google them and check other websites/forums,  ***or*** find their values on your own by experimenting with them in C or C++ .

In VB hexadecimal numbers are represented by prepending the number with `&H`, whereas in C, C++, C# or alike they're prepended with `0x`.

Comment: Plus one. I think I got the wrong end of the stick with my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba : Not really. Even though it might not have answered the whole question, explaining what hexadecimal numbers are and how they work is also relevant. :)

Comment: what about how they work how to use them. why they are in hexa not decimal. how can i implement this. if any one make me understand it with example. i will be greatful

Comment: @jaysonbourn : Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. We're here to help you solve problems or answer specific, programming related questions. You are the one to do the research.

Comment: @jaysonbourn : The documentation explains how to use them. If not directly in the messages' articles then usually in the docs of the control they belong to. -- The reason they use hexadecimal instead of decimal is just for convenience I guess... As far as I know there is no specific reason. Using either form is fine since they're just different ways of representing a number.

Comment: @jaysonbourn : The best way to find examples is to look for C or C++ examples, as they are the languages utilizing these methods and constants. Focus on small pieces of code only, as the long ones might be too hard to "convert" to VB (there is no actual converter between the languages, you'll just have to try to reflect the same code in VB).

Answer (score 0):

In a forms editor each window/control has a `hwnd` property. For windows not created by your forms package you use the API calls `FindWindow` (easiest but not reliable) or `EnumWindows`. Also `GetForegroundWindow` and `GetDesktopWindow`.

To find out the value of constants you download the C header files as part of the Windows SDK https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk. It also has the documentation for all these API calls. This is online documentation listing all the windows' functions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx.